# How to get git changed files in pull-request in Jenkins

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I run Jenkins with docker slaves and I'm trying to get the name of changed files(in the merge request) so I can do some further automation against those.

Unfortunately any variation of `git diff`(--name-only) is not producing any stdout in Jenkin's console. `git status` is working fine though.

**How can I capture the names of change files in the commit/merge request?** It doesn't have to be a CLI I'm happy to use web-hooks(gitlab-ce) although I have not seen one with that information yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

when you are running `git diff` in your jenkins job, there are no **unstaged changes** so it is totally normal that `git diff` shows nothing. `git status` will probably also tell you that everything is ok.

If you want to list the changed files in your pull-request, jenkins does not know about that. In any case you need the **name of the branch you are merging into**. Probably jenkins has set the `CHANGE_TARGET` variable; so then you could run:

```
git --no-pager diff origin/$CHANGE_TARGET --name-only
```

or something like that.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, it works if I hard-code the branch name( i.e. origin/prod). Any idea why it's not working when I run `git diff --name-only $GIT_COMMIT $GIT_BRANCH` or `git --no-pager diff $GIT_BRANCH --name-only` the variables are working fine if i do `echo`

Comment: well then it seems like your variables are not evaluated. It depends how you call this command? if you use a jenkinsfile note the difference between single and double quotes (sh "" vs sh''). In general double quotes means variables are evaluated.

Comment: I just run the Jenkins commands line for line and it's as you said, since it's in detached head at the commit.